# Are there any window events triggered if user "pulls the plug" and shuts down their computer?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a website, and I only want the client to be able to have 1 WebSocket connection at a time (when they open another tab while there is already another connection display, I display an error to them).

I'm working on a client-side solution where I update a flag in local storage to true when the connection is requested (It won't request if the flag is already true) then I listen for the `beforeunload` event and set the local storage flag to false if that tab had an open connection.

This seems to be working great except for the edge case of when a user shuts down their computer abruptly and thus beforeunload never fires, so when they turn their computer back on the local storage flag is stuck at true and they are stuck not being able to connect in any tabs.

**Is there an event that will be called before the shutdown where I can set my local storage flag to false?**

If not is there another solution for the client to keep track that it has only 1 WebSocket connection across all tabs so it can block a connection if there is already one?

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.setFlagToFalse);
```

Comment: no. A computer without power can't trigger an event in a browser on that computer - you'll need a smarter server side

Comment: I am aware that server side is the ideal solution however for this use case it's not mission critical and I want a client-side solution. All I want is for only 1 websocket connect open at once (if websocket connect, then don't connect), I'm thinking there has to be away to achieve this client side, and my solution works great except for this single edge case.

Comment: maybe you should try to find out how chrome finds out that it recovered from a crash (or the exact same scenario you mentioned) & gives users option to `restore tabs`. Don't know the same is true for other browsers though.
PS: maybe the flag should be your websocket connection & you should try to reuse it in such cases. If the websocket is invalid/errors out, try to reconnect?

Comment: use a timestamp instead of a flag

Comment: Why can you not periodically request a new websocket connection from other tabs, and return an error with a retry timestamp if the user already has another connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As correctly stated in Jaromanda's comment, a computer without power can not emit an Event to the browser (which doesn't even exist anymore...).

However, one solution to your root problem is to listen to the [storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/storage) event.

This event will fire across all the Windows that do share the same Storage area, when an other Window will make any modification to this Storage.

So we can use it as a mean to communicate between Windows from the same domain, in *almost* real time. This means that you don't have to keep your flag up to date, you can now know directly if an other Window is already active.

Here is a basic implementation. I'll let you the joy of making it more suited to your needs.

```
let alone = true; // a flag to know if we are alone
onstorage = e => { // listen to the storage event
  if(e.key === 'am_I_alone') {
    if(e.newValue === 'just checking') { // someone else is asking for permission
      localStorage.am_I_alone = 'false'; // refuse
    }
    else if(e.newValue === 'false') { // we've been refused access
      alone = false;
    }
  }
};

localStorage.am_I_alone = 'just checking'; // trigger the event on the other Windows

setTimeout(()=>{ // let them a little time to answer
  if(alone) { // no response, we're good to go
    // so the next one can trigger the event
    localStorage.am_I_alone = "true";
    startWebSocket();
  }
  else { // we've been rejected...
    error();
  }
}, 500);
```

#### [Live Plnkr](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/IDy0rOZpEyRuoX90?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Comment: Love this solution. Will implement now and see how it holds up. One question though. Why 500ms? Shouldn't I be able to make the user only wait say 50ms. 99.999% of the time 50ms would suffice right? Would rather not make the user wait extra if not necessary.

Comment: Just safety... 500 is indeed big, but blurred windows are throttled, so the event might not fire before 50ms. with 200ms at the end of the page load event, you should be fine though. And you could even add an other else in the onstorage event handler so that when the master sees that an other Window mistakenly though it was alone, it says it it's actually not and the other window closes the connection. But as I said, "I'll let you the joy of making it more suited to your needs."