# WebRTC both remote and local video is displayed with local stream

Tags: javascript, webrtc

hello i am newbie in WebRTC and i tried this code

```
  const yourVideo = document.querySelector("#face_cam_vid");
 const theirVideo = document.querySelector("#thevid");

 (async () => {
 if (!("mediaDevices" in navigator) || !("RTCPeerConnection" in window)) {
  alert("Sorry, your browser does not support WebRTC.");
  return;
 }
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, 
  audio: true});
  yourVideo.srcObject = stream;

  const configuration = {
  iceServers: [{urls: "stun:stun.1.google.com:19302"}]
  };
const yours = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
const theirs = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

for (const track of stream.getTracks()) {
  yours.addTrack(track, stream);
}
theirs.ontrack = e => theirVideo.srcObject = e.streams[0];

yours.onicecandidate = e => theirs.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);
theirs.onicecandidate = e => yours.addIceCandidate(e.candidate);

const offer = await yours.createOffer();
await yours.setLocalDescription(offer);
await theirs.setRemoteDescription(offer);

const answer = await theirs.createAnswer();
await theirs.setLocalDescription(answer);
await yours.setRemoteDescription(answer);
})();
```

and it works but partly https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMX5g.jpg .   in short i am creating ONE-to-ONE random video chatting like in omegle but this code displays both  "remote"(stranger's) and "local"("mine")  video with my local stream but all i want is , user wait for second user to have video chat and when third user enters it should wait for fourth and etc. i hope someone will help me with that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're confusing a local-loop demo—what you have—with a chat room.

A [**local-loop demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/yxbLvjm6/) is a short-circuit client-only proof-of-concept, linking two peer connections on the same page to each other. Utterly useless, except to prove the API works and the browser can talk to itself.

It contains `localPeerConnection` and `remotePeerConnection`—or `pc1` and `pc2`—and is not how one would typically write WebRTC code. It leaves out signaling.

Signaling is hard to demo without a server, but I show people this [**tab demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/2yLakm60/). Right-click and open it in two adjacent windows, and click the `Call!` button on one to call the other. It uses `localSocket`, a non-production hack I made using localStorage for signaling.

Just as useless, a tab-demo looks more like real code:

```
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection();

call.onclick = async () => {
  video.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true, audio:true});
  for (const track of video.srcObject.getTracks()) {
    pc.addTrack(track, video.srcObject);
  }
};

pc.ontrack = e => video.srcObject = e.streams[0];
pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => console.log(pc.iceConnectionState);
pc.onicecandidate = ({candidate}) => sc.send({candidate});
pc.onnegotiationneeded = async e => {
  await pc.setLocalDescription(await pc.createOffer());
  sc.send({sdp: pc.localDescription});
}

const sc = new localSocket();
sc.onmessage = async ({data: {sdp, candidate}}) => {
  if (sdp) {
    await pc.setRemoteDescription(sdp);
    if (sdp.type == "offer") {
      await pc.setLocalDescription(await pc.createAnswer());
      sc.send({sdp: pc.localDescription});
    }
  } else if (candidate) await pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
}
```

There's a single `pc`—your half of the call—and there's an `onmessage` signaling callback to handle the timing-critical asymmetric offer/answer negotiation correctly. Same JS on both sides.

This still isn't a **chat-room**. For that you need server logic to determine how people meet, and a web socket server for signaling. Try [this tutorial on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling) which culminates in a [chat demo](https://webrtc-from-chat.glitch.me/).

Comment: For your localSocket, just fast read it, but it sounds you are polling the Storage. You might be interested in the [storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/storage)  which will let you know when an other window modified the current window's Storage Area. You can see a rough demo of such a window messaging system in [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51777829/are-there-any-window-events-triggered-if-user-pulls-the-plug-and-shuts-down-th/51778107#51778107)

Comment: actually  i cant understand which i  cant get which one is MYVIDEO (local), and THEIRVIDEO (remote) and also i can not understand why do i need onmessage event

Comment: and actually i tried MDN but its kinda obscure  because there is messaging system too , so because of that code is obscure thats why i posted here but thanks for that answer , i tried array of connections but it did not worked so i'll be very glad if i find answer here BTW thanks for answering me second time <3

Comment: A traditional message system and WebRTC share the same challenge of discovering participants, which is outside of WebRTC. Besides, the message system is needed anyway for signaling.

Comment: i also does not use usernames it is just pure javascript and this whole code is on usernames and coz i am newbie i can not transform MDN code like i work with users ,(i use document.hasFocus() method )   BTW  that chat demo ain't workin' . i tried my best but coz i did not reach my aim i posted it here 


also what u mean  with its hard to show people demo without **server**  i thought only server u need is iceserver , do i need expressjs also?

Comment: also that demo is not displaying my Media ? (jsfiddle)

Comment: @codR Which of the two jsfiddle demos? The one to open in two adjacent windows? What browser are you on? wfm in Chrome and Firefox. About needing a signaling server, I believe I've already pointed you to enough information. In the chat demo, log in from two windows with different user names, then click on the other user in the list to open a video call.