# PeerConnection create answer

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I would like create WebRTC connection on 2 devices.

On my first device (Initiator), i create my Offer with this method :

```
  createOffer() {
    const { pc } = this;

    pc.onnegotiationneeded = () => {
      pc.createOffer()
        .then(offer => pc.setLocalDescription(offer))
        .then(() => {
          this.setState({
            offer: JSON.stringify(pc.localDescription)
          });
        });
    };
  }
```

And on my second device (Receiver), i create the answer :

```
  createAnswer() {
    const { pc } = this;
    const { dataOffer } = this.state;

    if (dataOffer) {
      const sd = new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(dataOffer));

      pc.setRemoteDescription(sd)
        .then(() => pc.createAnswer())
        .then(answer => {
          this.setState({
            offer: JSON.stringify(answer)
          });

          return pc.setLocalDescription(answer);
        });
    }
  }
```

But, after send Answer on first device, i've this error : `PeerConnection cannot create an answer in a state other than have-remote-offer or have-local-pranswer.`

When Initiator receive the answer, i run `createAnswer` method with answer data, That may be the problem ?

I don't really understand what method/event i need use after receive the answer :/

EDIT with new method for Initiator device :

```
  receiveAnswer() {
    const { pc } = this;
    const { dataOffer } = this.state;
    const sd = new RTCSessionDescription(JSON.parse(dataOffer));

    pc.setRemoteDescription(sd);
  }
```

But the connection state stay on `checking` :(

You can see my `componentDidMount` :

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const { pc } = this;

    pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => {
      this.setState({
        connectionState: pc.iceConnectionState
      });
    };

    pc.onaddstream = ({ stream }) => {
      if (stream) {
        this.setState({
          receiverVideoURL: stream.toURL()
        });
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: Where's your `setRemoteDescription(answer)` code on the first device? Also, how many tracks have you added, and which browser(s) have you tried?

Comment: Hi ! I call `createAnswer` method on first device when answer is receive. `setRemoteDescription` is used in this method. I try with only 2 devices, in React Native App, not browser, Android only.

Comment: Why would you `createAnswer` when you receive an answer? That doesn't make any sense. Sure it calls `setRemoteDescription(dataOffer)`, but even if `dataOffer` is the answer (is it?), it also subsequently calls `createAnswer()` again, which is probably where your error comes from.

Comment: Oh yes, i think that the problem too. I've edit my first post with new method `receiveAnswer`, runned on initiator device, `dataOffer` is answer sdp. With this method, the connection state stay on `checking` :/

Comment: Next you need to trickle ICE candidates and `addIceCandidate`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53403324/918910).

Comment: Hi jib, than you for your help. I use webrtc on offline app for now. I try to connect by sending the Offer and Answer by slack or email (for test only). I need to use Ice candidates ?