# Why does the WebRTC stream to peer sample have two RTCPeerConnection objects

Tags: webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

I am studying [this sample](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/capture/video-pc) and working to modify it so that video can be streamed from one browser instance and then appear on the second instance. 
I have a few questions:

Is the reason that the ICEServers array is empty because of localhost? Would this still be okay running on two browser instances?

I also don't understand why there are two RTCPeerConnection objects? Shouldn't there only be a single object since the RTCPeerConnection class contains methods for both local and remote?

Comment: Please post *relevant parts* of that sample here into your question, don't rely on external sites to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: But, it appears to be a demo within one browser window. You need two sides to a conversation, each with their own WebRTC object. If that happens within the same browser window, then you need two objects in one script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebRTC both remote and local video is displayed with local stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398178/webrtc-both-remote-and-local-video-is-displayed-with-local-stream)

Comment: @deceze thanks - makes sense! Just confusing when first introduced to this api :) If you post an answer I'll be happy to accept it.