# WebRTC getting Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on RTCPeerConnection error on console but can still display remote and local videos

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, socket.io, webrtc

I am trying to connect two peers using webRTC. I am able to display both local and remote videos correctly but as soon as the remote video appears, the candidate object becomes `null` and on the console it logs the following error message.

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': Candidate missing values for both sdpMid and sdpMLineIndex
```

I am using two separate laptops to test the connection and since both remote and local videos are showing, I think that I have connected two peers successfully but I'm not sure because of the error message.

Any idea on why this might be happening? Am I even successfully connecting the two peers?

Below is the code.

Thank you!

**Frontend**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.room = 'test-room';
    this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
    this.localPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
      iceServers: [
        {
          urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
        }
      ]
    });
    this.remotePeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
      iceServers: [
        {
          urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
        }
      ]
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.socket.on('connect', () => {
      this.socket.emit('join', this.room, err => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          this.socket.on('offer', offer => {
            console.log('OFFER RECEIVED: ', offer);
            this.createAnswer(offer);
          });

          this.socket.on('candidate', candidate => {
            console.log('CANDIDATE RECEIVED', candidate);
            this.localPeerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate).catch(error => console.error(error));
            this.remotePeerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate).catch(error => console.error(error));
          });

          this.socket.on('answer', answer => {
            console.log('ANSWER RECEIVED:', answer);
            this.localPeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(answer);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

  startCall = async () => {
    this.localPeerConnection.onicecandidate = e => {
      const iceCandidate = e.candidate;
      this.socket.emit('candidate', { room: this.room, candidate: iceCandidate });
      console.log('candidate generated', e.candidate);
    };

    this.localPeerConnection.ontrack = e => {
      this.remoteVideo.srcObject = e.streams[0];
      console.log('REMOTE STREAM?: ', e.streams[0]);
    };

    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { width: 150, height: 150 }, audio: false });
      for (const track of stream.getTracks()) {
        this.localPeerConnection.addTrack(track, stream);
      }

      this.localVideo.srcObject = stream;
      console.log('LOCAL STREAMS: ', this.localPeerConnection.getLocalStreams())

      return this.createOffer();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  createOffer = async () => {
    try {
      const offer = await this.localPeerConnection.createOffer();
      await this.localPeerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
      await this.remotePeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(offer);

      this.socket.emit('offer', { room: this.room, offer });
      console.log('SENDING OFFER: ', offer);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  createAnswer = async description => {
    this.remotePeerConnection.onicecandidate = e => {
      const iceCandidate = e.candidate;
      this.socket.emit('candidate', { room: this.room, candidate: iceCandidate });
      console.log('candidate generated', e.candidate);
    };

    this.remotePeerConnection.ontrack = e => {
      this.remoteVideo.srcObject = e.streams[0];
    };

    this.remotePeerConnection.setRemoteDescription(description)
      .then(() => navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { width: 150, height: 150 }, audio: false }))
      .then(stream => {
        for (const track of stream.getTracks()) {
          this.remotePeerConnection.addTrack(track, stream);
        }

        this.localVideo.srcObject = stream;

        return this.remotePeerConnection.createAnswer();
      })
      .then(answer => {
        this.remotePeerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
        return answer;
      })
      .then(answer => {
        this.socket.emit('answer', { room: this.room, answer });
        console.log('SENDING ANSWER: ', answer);
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Webrtc</h1>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.startCall}>CALL</button>
        </div>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
          <div>
            <video id='localVideo' autoPlay muted playsInline ref={ref => this.localVideo = ref} />
            <p>LOCAL VIDEO</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <video id='remoteVideo' autoPlay muted playsInline ref={ref => this.remoteVideo = ref} />
            <p>REMOTE VIDEO</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Server**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const connections = [];
const clients = [];

io.set('origins', '*:*');
io.on('connection', socket => {
  connections.push(socket);
  clients.push({ socket_id: socket.id });
  console.log('Connected: %s sockets connected ', connections.length);

  socket.on('join', (room, callback) => {
    const clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room];
    const numClients = (typeof clients !== 'undefined') ? clients.length : 0;
    console.log('joined room', room);
    if (numClients > 1) {
      return callback('already_full');
    }
    else if (numClients === 1) {
      socket.join(room);
      io.in(room).emit('ready');
    }
    else {
      socket.join(room);
    }

    callback();
  });

  socket.on('offer', (data) => {
    const { room, offer } = data;
    console.log('offer from: ', offer);
    socket.to(room).emit('offer', offer);
  });

  socket.on('answer', (data) => {
    const { room, answer } = data;
    console.log('answer from: ', answer);
    socket.to(room).emit('answer', answer);
  });

  socket.on('candidate', (data) => {
    const { room, candidate } = data;
    console.log('candidate: ', candidate);
    socket.to(room).emit('candidate', candidate);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
    console.log('Disconnected: %s sockets connected, ', connections.length);
    clients.forEach((client, i) => {
      if (client.socket_id === socket.id) {
        clients.splice(i, 1);
      }
    });
  });
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**UPDATE**

After reading jib's comment, I have modified my client js as follows.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.room = 'test-room';
    this.socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
    this.peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
      iceServers: [
        {
          urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'
        }
      ]
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.socket.on('connect', () => {
      this.socket.emit('join', this.room, err => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          this.socket.on('offer', offer => {
            console.log('OFFER RECEIVED: ', offer);
            this.createAnswer(offer);
          });

          this.socket.on('candidate', candidate => {
            this.peerConnection.addIceCandidate(candidate).catch(error => console.error(error));
            console.log('CANDIDATE RECEIVED', candidate);
          });

          this.socket.on('answer', answer => {
            console.log('ANSWER RECEIVED:', answer);
            this.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(answer);
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }

  startCall = async () => {
    this.peerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => console.log('ICE CONNECTION STATE: ', this.peerConnection.iceConnectionState);

    this.peerConnection.onicecandidate = e => {
      const iceCandidate = e.candidate;
      this.socket.emit('candidate', { room: this.room, candidate: iceCandidate });
      console.log('candidate generated', e.candidate);
    };

    this.peerConnection.ontrack = e => {
      this.remoteVideo.srcObject = e.streams[0];
      console.log('REMOTE STREAMS: ', this.peerConnection.getRemoteStreams());
    };

    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { width: 150, height: 150 }, audio: false });
      for (const track of stream.getTracks()) {
        this.peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream);
      }

      this.localVideo.srcObject = stream;
      console.log('LOCAL STREAMS: ', this.peerConnection.getLocalStreams())

      return this.createOffer();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  createOffer = async () => {
    try {
      const offer = await this.peerConnection.createOffer();
      await this.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
      this.socket.emit('offer', { room: this.room, offer });
      console.log('SENDING OFFER: ', offer);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  createAnswer = async description => {
    this.peerConnection.onicecandidate = e => {
      const iceCandidate = e.candidate;
      this.socket.emit('candidate', { room: this.room, candidate: iceCandidate });
      console.log('candidate generated', e.candidate);
    };

    this.peerConnection.ontrack = e => {
      this.remoteVideo.srcObject = e.streams[0];
    };

    this.peerConnection.setRemoteDescription(description)
      .then(() => navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: { width: 150, height: 150 }, audio: false }))
      .then(stream => {
        for (const track of stream.getTracks()) {
          this.peerConnection.addTrack(track, stream);
        }

        this.localVideo.srcObject = stream;

        return this.peerConnection.createAnswer();
      })
      .then(answer => {
        this.peerConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
        return answer;
      })
      .then(answer => {
        this.socket.emit('answer', { room: this.room, answer });
        console.log('SENDING ANSWER: ', answer);
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Webrtc</h1>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.startCall}>CALL</button>
        </div>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
          <div>
            <video id='localVideo' autoPlay muted playsInline ref={ref => this.localVideo = ref} />
            <p>LOCAL VIDEO</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <video id='remoteVideo' autoPlay muted playsInline ref={ref => this.remoteVideo = ref} />
            <p>REMOTE VIDEO</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The error on my console still persists... any idea why?

Comment: You're setting the same candidates on both sides. Why do you have two peers in the same JS? You don't need signaling at all if you're just doing a local-loop demo. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53398178/webrtc-both-remote-and-local-video-is-displayed-with-local-stream/53403324#53403324) for help.

Comment: Hi jib, after looking at the answer from the link, I have modified the code a little bit. But the error on my console still persists. For further clarification, I have my signaling server hosted on heroku and I am also able to see both local and remote video when I make a call. Any idea on what could be causing the error on the console?

Comment: Maybe there is an issue with Google Chrome. I tested this on Firefox and Safari and I'm not getting any errors on those browsers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> The error on my console still persists... any idea why?

This is a [known bug in Chrome](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=978582) (please ★ it to have it fixed!)

To see it, type the following into web console in Chrome 78:

```js
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(); pc.setRemoteDescription(await pc.createOffer())
```

then

```js
pc.addIceCandidate(undefined)
```

and it produces:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection':
 Candidate missing values for both sdpMid and sdpMLineIndex
```

Now try

```js
pc.addIceCandidate()
```

and it says:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection':
 1 argument required, but only 0 present.
```

Both are in violation of the [latest spec](https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#dom-peerconnection-addicecandidate), which says that `pc.addIceCandidate()` is *"an end-of-candidates indication"* that *"applies to all media descriptions."*

#### Workaround

You can safely ignore this error until Chrome fixes it, or catch the `TypeError` and suppress it.

I recommend against `if (candidate) pc.addIceCandidate(candidate)` as a workaround, as once Chrome fixes this, it would prevent `iceConnectionState` from ever going to the `"completed"` state in Chrome or any other browser.

Comment: After reading your answer, I just decided to ignore the error. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @jib, I am facing this error and from your answer, it seems that chrome didn't solve it yet!! Is it so?

Comment: @WagnerPatriota Actually, the upstream bug was recently fixed, and this works for me now in Chrome 90. 

Comment: Still seeing this issue in Chrome 91.0.4472.101

Comment: @AzimjonIlkhomov WFM in 91.0.4472.101 on mac. I see `Promise<fulfilled>: undefined` which I believe is correct. Are you entering the above verbatim into the console? What errors are you seeing?