# Should empty string icecandidate be added by addicecandidate?

Tags: webrtc, p2p, nat-traversal, rtcpeerconnection

My question is about webrtc negotiation.

There is a contradiction in many online tutorials and what is described in MDN.

In MDN, it says [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Connectivity)

> At the end of each generation of candidates, an end-of-candidates
>   notification is sent in the form of an RTCIceCandidate **whose candidate
>   property is an empty string. This candidate should still be added to
>   the connection using addIceCandidate() method**, as usual, in order to
>   deliver that notification to the remote peer.
>
> When there are no more candidates at all to be expected during the
>   current negotiation exchange, an end-of-candidates notification is
>   sent by delivering a RTCIceCandidate whose candidate property is null.
>   This message does not need to be sent to the remote peer. It's a
>   legacy notification of a state which can be detected instead by
>   watching for the iceGatheringState to change to complete, by watching
>   for the icegatheringstatechange event.

However, in the tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Signaling_and_video_calling), they introduce the following code

```
function handleICECandidateEvent(event) {
  if (event.candidate) {
    sendToServer({
      type: "new-ice-candidate",
      target: targetUsername,
      candidate: event.candidate
    });
  }
}
```

If candidate is an empty string, it will be evaluated falsy and not be sent via `sendToServer`.

More interestingly, even in a same article [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/icecandidate_event)

They have following sample code

```
rtcPeerConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
  if (event.candidate) {
    sendCandidateToRemotePeer(event.candidate)
  }
}
```

But right below this snippet, they say

> When an ICE negotiation session runs out of candidates to propose for
>   a given RTCIceTransport, it has completed gathering for a generation
>   of candidates. That this has occurred is indicated by an icecandidate
>   event **whose candidate string is empty ("")**.
>
> **You should deliver this to the remote peer just like any standard candidate, as described under Sharing a new candidate above**. This
>   ensures that the remote peer is given the end-of-candidates
>   notification as well.

Actually, I read many online tutorials but I have never seen anywhere where they handle the empty string candidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old spec did not require sending an empty candidate, but the new spec require send and addIceCandidate() an empty candidate.
Since Chrome is still an old specification, an empty candidate will cause an error when addedIceCandidate(), so I will not send it.

Comment: could you provide a link of the resource for your statement? I would like to keep track of the root problem and watch for until it supports to update my code accordingly

Comment: Please check this out for details
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58908081/webrtc-getting-failed-to-execute-addicecandidate-on-rtcpeerconnection-error-on